# C# - Using the QTLibrary control to get m4p metadata issue

Tags: c#, winforms, quicktime

I've run into a problem using the form Apple Quicktime Control while attempting to pull metadata from m4p files.

I've got an array of strings which hold the filepath of individual files and then I loop through them as follows:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    axQTControl1.URL = file;

    // Create new movie object
    QTOLibrary.QTMovie mov = new QTOLibrary.QTMovie();
    mov = axQTControl1.Movie;

    string title = mov.get_Annotation((int)QTAnnotationEnum.qtAnnotationFullName);
}
```

However, I run into the issue that the only real methods I can call from my `QTMovie` object include `get_Dimensions` or `get_Rectangle`.

According to [this tutorial, however,](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50056/Read-M4A-tags-in-C) I should be able to use get_Annotation to pull the meta data.

I'm having a hard time finding any documentation on this and that tutorial is about the only help I've gotten. If anyone has any idea or a link to get me going in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. This works for m4a and m4p files and probably others but I haven't tested m4b and the like.

```
using QTOLibrary;

foreach (string file in files)
{
    axQTControl1.URL = file;

    // Create new movie object
    QTOLibrary.QTMovie mov = new QTOLibrary.QTMovie();
    mov = axQTControl1.Movie;

    string title = mov.Annotation[(int)QTAnnotationsEnum.qtAnnotationFullName];
    string artist = mov.Annotation[(int)QTAnnotationsEnum.qtAnnotationArtist];
    string album = mov.Annotation[(int)QTAnnotationsEnum.qtAnnotationAlbum];
    songs.Add(new Song(title, album, artist, file));
    WriteLine("Evaluated " + title);
}

// Make sure the previous file is not in use
// This will prevent an IOException when the file is in use and cannot be moved
axQTControl1.URL = "";
```